# jquery return of trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am using JQuery to attach a function to an element:

```
$("button").on("random",
               function() {
```

but I want the function to return a result:

```
                 alert('called');
                 return 'button has been clicked';
               }
```

The problem is, when I used 'trigger' to trigger the function, the function executes, but the result isn't returned - the JQuery element (I think) is returned instead.

```
$("a").on("click",
          function() {alert($('button').trigger('random'));}
         )
```

How do I write or call the function so that its result is returned?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cs3cqv3z/3

Thank you.

Comment: Do not alert again when calling the trigger. The function does the "alert" itself.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour, the alerts are there to reveal the bug, indeed the trigger results in two alerts in a row - for the triggered function and to show the data returned. But - the data returned isn't the result of the function triggered, that's my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return a value to a trigger but you can store its value. One way is to pass an object to the call and storing value in it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").on("random",
                   function(e, obj) {
                     alert('called');
                     obj.value= 'button has been clicked';
                   }
                  );
    $("a").on("click",
              function()
              {
var infoObj = {value: ''};               $('button').trigger('random',[infoObj]);
console.log(infoObj.value)}
             )
  }
)
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cs3cqv3z/5/)**

```
Another way is using jQuery's `.data()` method.

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").on("random",
                   function(e, obj) {
                     alert('called');
                     obj.value= 'button has been clicked';
                   }
                  );
    $("a").on("click",
              function()
              {
var infoObj = {value: ''};               $('button').trigger('random');
alert(infoObj.value)}
             )
  }
)
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/cs3cqv3z/6/)

Another method is to use the `.triggerHandler()` instead of the `.trigger()`.
However I would suggest you to go through the docs first and see if it fits your requirement. It does solve the problem though.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").on("random",
          function(e) {
               alert('called');
              return 'button has been clicked';
          }
     );
    $("a").on("click", function() {             
                alert($('button').triggerHandler('random'));
        })
})
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cs3cqv3z/7/)**

Comment: I did think of that, but feel it's rather messy... If there isn't a better option in the next few days, I'll accept yours.

Comment: @boisvert Added another solution. Kindly check

Comment: thanks, I should have thought of triggerHandler! And it explains why the function's result doesn't appear, as the trigger calls the function as part of an event response.